# Angular 5 plugin dependencies

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

If I use Angular plugins having own dependencies managed by Node and a `package.json` will the total list of dependencies the sum of it? Even if they have the same dependencies? So plugin `1` has 1000 dependencies and plugin `2` 900 dependencies. 850 dependencies are the same. Will the total list of dependencies for the application 1900 or 200?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No,

NPM knows how to deal with it. If one of your modules/dep have the same dep (version...etc), it will be downloaded once by npm and webpack should manage it too.

Comment: This is also true for plugins having own packages? I thought it's only valid for components.

Comment: I don't understand your question. There is 2 aspects. How npm is managing your deps and how webpack is managing your deps.